# SQL multiple JOIN to the same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

**outcome table**

outcome_id, outcome

**refs table**

refs_id, branchno, colleagueid, colleague2id, datestamp

**colleague Table**

colleague_id, name, branch

Here is the mysqli statement that I am using to draw the colleague name rather than the number. This also works for the outcome instead of outcome_id.

The issue i'm having is I cannot join colleague2id to a name from the colleague table.

```
SELECT * FROM refs
JOIN colleague ON colleague.colleague_id=refs.colleagueid
JOIN outcome ON outcome.outcome_id=refs.outcome
WHERE branchno ='{$_SESSION["branchinfo"]["storeno"]}'
```

Output into PHP

```
echo "<td>".$row["refs_id"])."</td>" . "
    <td>".$row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>".$row['colleague2id'] . "</td>
    <td>".$row['outcome'] . "</td>
```

How can I get `$row['colleague2id']` to show **colleague.name** instead of the id number?

Sorry if this isn't formatted correctly its my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are two `colleagueid`s in `refs` table, you'd need to `JOIN` the `colleague` table twice to be able to get names for both those columns.

The query should be:

```
SELECT refs_id, branchno, colleagueid, colleague2id, datestamp,
       c1.name AS colleague1name, c2.name AS colleague2name,
       outcome_id, o.outcome
    FROM refs
         JOIN colleague c1 ON c1.colleague_id = refs.colleagueid
         JOIN colleague c2 ON c2.colleague_id = refs.colleague2id
         JOIN outcome   o  ON o.outcome_id    = refs.outcome
    WHERE branchno ='{$_SESSION["branchinfo"]["storeno"]}'
```

Then, PHP can access the names as:

```
$row['colleague1name']
$row['colleague2name']
```

The only other thing which should be considered is that the query above is prone to SQL Injection attacks and hence prepared statements using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) should be implemented instead.

Comment: This works great for the colleague names but outcome has stopped working?

Comment: Well, it's because you'll have to include those columns explicitly in the `SELECT` statement. Please check the updated answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: Outcome wouldn't work as I had a table name and column name the same. Poor naming from me there but its working great now thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I overlooked that too. Ideally it shouldn't so be the case that both the column and table names are alike. However, just in case you find yourself in an unavoidable situation to deal with that, then please have a look at the edited query to see how the conflict can be possibly resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need  two join for colleague table  (using alias a and b )

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM refs
  JOIN colleague  as a ON a.colleague_id=refs.colleagueid
  JOIN colleague  as b ON b.colleague_id=refs.colleague2id
  JOIN outcome ON outcome.outcome_id=refs.outcome
  WHERE branchno ='{$_SESSION["branchinfo"]["storeno"]}'
```

but for a clear select  you should set explictally the columns name